# MQTT Service for iOS Push Notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, mqtt

The low reliability of GCM on Android is such that I have moved to another service to handle push messages: Pushy, (https://pushy.me/)

The service relies on MQTT, and from my experience as well as many other reviews, the real time feature-set holds up to its name and rarely does a message get dropped. However, contacting support, they noted that there is no iOS integration and only support Android.

I have searched widely but have not found a suitable replacement for iOS that supports MQTT out of the box.

Is there such a service available to allow for more dependable push messages?

Comment: Pushy supports iOS now (piggybacking on the reliable APNs): https://pushy.me/docs/ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is iOS's limitations on background services makes staying connected to a MQTT broker difficult.

Apple have a list of use cases that are allowed to run in the background, the list can be found in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW4)

If your app does not conform to this list it is likely to not get approved for the App Store.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a completed service this more dependable, I don't want to build from scratch.

Comment: What I'm saying is that there aren't any because of this problem

Comment: So APNS is the best bet for allowing real-time chatting in my app?

Comment: Update - Pushy supports iOS now, by routing through the reliable, built-in APNs!