# How to run MQTT service in background for infinite time on ios with objective c in native application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mqtt, iot, background-mode

I want to run my iot app in background mode in iphone forever .I have googled a lot .But not finding any solution .
All the devices should run MQTT service in background mode It just not about pushing notifications i want to MQTT service would always connect to MQTT client  .
Also am curious to know how whatsapp run  in background mode.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please check this link for MQTT queries: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36522487/7752480

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MQTT Service for iOS Push Notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522224/mqtt-service-for-ios-push-notifications)

Comment: VoIP apps have a specific background mode. You can't run a general task, like an MQTT service, in the background. iOS devices are not general purpose computers; they are mobile devices. If you want to receive messages then it would be better to have a server somewhere that subscribes to the required topic and sends a push notification to the iOS device.

Comment: please send me the sample code ,how it will work.Thanku so much for guiding

Comment: @ReevanshiGarg, when there are messages pending in the MQTT channel, post a silent push notification (APNS) to the device upon which you can initiate a background task for a limited time to pull the required data.